# Windows 10 resetting PC at the end of Windows Phone SDK install

Tags: windows-10-preview, windows-phone, sdk

I am trying to use Windows Phone SDK on Windows 10 (Build 10130). I have tried installing it but it always fails at the Finalizer step of the install. And by failure I mean it resets the PC.

I checked the logs in Event Viewer/Windows Logs/Application:

[image]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/EIiFfvV.png]

Any ideas? Is this a known issue?

Comment: Have you check the insider website, which as a list of known issues, to see if this is a known issue?

Comment: the latest public matching WDK/SDK was for Build 10074. Go back to this older Build and try again or wait for the RTM and an updated SDK/WDK.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks, I will wait for now I guess

To Ramhound: Yes, I did check it, although it is possible that I have skimmed over something. It is safe to say, that to the best of my knowledge this question has not been asked in any other media in the internet. But then again, I am just a human being with my errors: ) That is why I asked whether this is a known issue or not.